# Why limits of functions which are not $\frac{0}{0}$ have an asymptote

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

I just finished learning limits from Thomas Calculus. While doing it exercises I figured out that if $f(x)$ has numerator $0$ and denominator $0$. For example:

$f(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{ x}$

$f(x) = \frac{\cos(x) }{ x }$

as $x \to 0$.

The first one is $\frac{0}{0}$ and doesn't have an asymptote on $x = 0$; but the second one does. Are they even related? How? 
And why is the function
 $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2} - x}$ different from 
 $f(x) = \frac{x}{ 1 - x}$?
In the second one it looks like a line is connecting the two sides of this. 
I'd be happy if anyone could help me understand these asymptotes better.

Comment: My answer relies on Taylor series (which is probably the easiest way to explain the connection in my opinion) but I realize I forgot to ask if you are familiar with them.  If you are not,  then in essence for most basic functions you'll see you can find a polynomial that will be very close to the function at that point (but might be vary far off as you go away from that point).  The cool thing about the cosine polynomial is that it is EXACTLY equal to the cosine function everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the function $f$ is said to have an asymptote at $c$ if either $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\pm\infty$ or $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

Note that the function need not be defined at $c$, but $c$ should be a limit point of the domain of $f$ (some texts require $f$ is defined either in a left or a right neighborhood of $c$, with the possible exclusion of $c$).

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}=0
$$
the function $f(x)=(1-\cos x)/x$ has no asymptote at $0$. On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\cos x}{x}=-\infty,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos x}{x}=\infty,
$$
so the function $x\mapsto\frac{\cos x}{x}$ has an asymptote at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the Taylor series for cosine is
\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{24} +\cdots$

When we divide by $x$ alone we get
$\frac{\cos x}{x}  = \frac 1x -\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{24} +\cdots$ The $\frac 1x$ out front gives the asymptote.

When we subtract the series from 1 first we get
$1-\cos x = \frac{x^2}{2}- \frac{x^4}{24} +\cdots$ so that we don't get a $\frac 1x$ term when we divide by $x$.  This leaves us with
$\frac{1-\cos x}{x} = \frac{x}{2}- \frac{x^3}{24} +\cdots$

To answer your second question,  both functions you mention have asymptotes (one at $x=\sqrt{2}$ and the other at $x=1$)  so I fail to understand your question. It may be you are witnessing a graphing error,  but that is due to the software trying to correct for a "mistake" it believes exists at the point of the asymptote by drawing a straight line across.  This fixes many similar issues when graphing that arise from rounding errors or such,  but does have the consequence of causing errors such as the one you may have witnessed.  If I am wrong in my interpretation let me know.

Comment: Here is part of an article on asymptotes : The vertical asymptotes will occur at those values of x for which the denominator
is equal to zero: ... Some Caclulations of denominator = 0 ..  Since $\sqrt{8}$ is not a real number, the graph will have no vertical asymptotes. I don't understand why

Comment: @ErfanAhmadi well, now I'm more confused. First and foremost, $\sqrt{8}$ ***is*** a real number. Secondly, your original post mentions $\sqrt{2}$. Is there anyway you could send the actual article, or a link to a photo of it?. It is true that vertical asymptotes will occur only when the denominator goes to $0$ (but just because the denominator goes to $0$ does not imply an asymptote,  as you noticed already)

Comment: Page 3 Example 2 : https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg2snq6oofurbn1/vertical-horizontal.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @ErfanAhmadi ah, the example is not $\sqrt{8}$ it's $\sqrt{-8} = 8i$. The square roots of negative numbers are imaginary, and so they don't appear on a graph of real numbers (and because the discontinuity is at an imaginary value, you'll only get issues like asymptotes at that point if you graph the imaginary parts of the function)

Comment: @ErfanAhmadi basically,  when you find that the denominator is only 0 for an imaginary value then we know that no real number $x$ will make the denominator 0, so there can be no vertical asymptote

Comment: why do $\frac{0}{1}$ type and $\frac{0}{0}$ act like they do ?

Comment: @ErfanAhmadi the short reason is that,  for any integer $n$ other than $0$,  $\frac n0 = \pm \infty$,  while you can basically make $\frac 00$ equal anything you want.... The limit is different in every direction. Formally understanding two-sided limits is a calculus 3 topic, but this is a good layman video on the topic: https://youtu.be/BRRolKTlF6Q

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x}=\frac{\cos 0-\cos x}{x}=\frac{2\sin\frac{x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}}{x}=\sin\frac{x}{2}\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}$$
This tends to $0\cdot 1=0$ as $x\to 0$, so the limit is finite, so there is no asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, recall that $\cos(0)=1$ so the limit is of type $\frac{1}{0}$ not of type $\frac{0}{0}$ as in the first example. Also the two functions $f_1(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}-x}$ and $f_2(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-x}$ are very similar differing mainly in the location of the vertical asymptote. If you are using a graphing program it will plot points for $x$ values separated by some uniform distance $\Delta x$. If there is a vertical asymptote between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ then the software will incorrectly connect the two points with a straight line segment.

Comment: Exactly I know it's the type $\frac{1}{0}$ but what I don't understand is why do $\frac{0}{0}$ type and $\frac{1}{0}$ act like they do ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac 5 x \to \text{what, as }x\downarrow0\text{ ?}$$

The downward arrow means approaching $0$ from **above**; for the moment I'm not considering negative numbers.

Imagine $x$ is very very very close to $0$.  Say $x = \dfrac 1 {\text{1 million}}$.  Then $\dfrac 5 x$ is how many times $x$ goes into $5$.  It goes into $5$ no few than $5$ million times -- quite a large number.  Now cut $x$ down to $\dfrac 1 {\text{1 billion}}$ and $x$ goes into the numerator $5$ billion times.  You can make $x$ go into $5$ as large a number of times as you want by making $x$ small enough.  Thus $5/x$ goes to $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from above. So you have a vertical asymptote.

Now consider $\dfrac{3x} x$.  Make $x$ small and you also make $3x$ small.  The tiny number $x$ still goes into the numerator only $3$ times.  It approaches $3$, not $+\infty$.